# Pardot Dynamic Reply-to for list emails or Engagement Studio Emails

Tags: dynamic, reply, pardot

Many of the emails we are creating are global and have specific regional customer service departments. That said, the localized emails we are creating need to have dynamic reply-to addresses so that prospects will reach out to the customer service department associated with their country or region. Has anyone here been able to find a way to dynamically change the reply-to address for their emails in pardot? Has anyone tried or hardcoded a way to do this in the HTML?

So far I have researched all over online and in documentation and didnt find anything conclusive to whether this was possible. I assume pardot would tell me NO, but I want to know if anyone found a workaround for this.